# How can I make maven to use maven cetral repo?

Tags: java, maven

So my default maven settings.xml file in my ~/.m2/ folder is containing links to my work repositories. So whenever I run an install on my pom.xml's it try to fetch from the corp nexus maven repositories.

For a hobby project which I am just starting with I don't want to make use of the corp maven nexus, but to make use of the central maven repo. I don't want to replace the entire settings.xml as this would mean reloading the entire local maven repo once I switch back to my corp work.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What about commenting the the proxy / mirror declaration pointing to your corp Nexus?

Comment: Cant we do anything in the pom.xml iteself ? without touching the settings.xml?

Comment: "this would mean reloading the entire local maven repo". No, Maven will always look inside your repo before looking at remote repositories. I'm not sure what you really want here.

Comment: Doing something related to repositories in you pom is not a good idea...The settings.xml file is simply local...the pom is not...

Comment: @Ajay do you wish to still use your local repo cache in ~/.m2? How about specifying external settings file + external local repo cache though command line and using those?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following as your first repository in the repositories tag in the settings.xml

```
        <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
```

You may also want to use [profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html).  But, that is not a requirement.

You can also add a repository on your pom

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <url>http://rep1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Cant we do something in the pom.xml itself without touching the settings.xml >?